# Arch Linux; further restrict access to sudo

Tags: arch-linux, sudo, group

I'm setting up my Arch Linux system on VirtualBox, and I've gotten to the step of adding sudo, but I want to do something to further secure admin access.

I've created my own custom group, `gg3`, and added my user to the group. But I'd like to somehow require sudo to only allow access to users who are in both `wheel` and `gg3`. I've checked the sudo manual, I've tried googling it, but I haven't found anything. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible just using `sudo`

Comment: @rustyshackleford Yeah, I kinda figured. Thanks anyways. I'll leave this question open to see what other people put down.

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to do, when you could just make a third group (how about "sudoer") for "people that should be able to use `sudo`" (though I question what other purpose "wheel" has in this case). I'd guess you could make `sudo` executable only by members of the one group, and use the normal methods to allow use only by members of the other, but that's complicated, doesn't scale past two groups, and could confuse you later if you forgot you did it